# Approval flow in ms teams in power automate

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I know the fact that we can send approval emails to someone in power automate. Can we do the same in MS teams with the chat showing option approve or reject? If yes how to do it?

Comment: It happens automatically with the flow app. Is it not for you?

Answer (score 0):

When you start an approval flow in the SharePoint, it will automatically show in the Teams.

[image]